Curious mystery - local ping traffic takes down internet connectivity
I have several devices on my network that are setup to ping the router every minute (they run ping 192.168.1.1 in a chron job). The router is a Ubiquiti Dream Machine.
Somehow, this is causing my internet to go down constantly. The local network is fine (pings continue to work) but the WAN goes down and the internet is unreachable.
Note that the ping traffic is exclusively on the local network.
Turning off the pings and rebooting the router stops the behavior.
Any thoughts on how to get to the bottom of this curious mystery?

What's the symptoms? What does your logs show?

Sure which logs?

For instance the logs of your router. In addition it's interesting to know how you discover that the internet connectivity is down.
